# Need timer that can auto close / open an application then open another

Tags: windows, timer, alarm-clock

Does anyone know about a program that could auto-close just say for example a game on Steam at a certain time, then open Visual Studio and Firefox after that program closes? Tried looking for an hour or so but I can't even seem to find what to search for. Thanks!

Comment: I'm 95% sure AutoIt can do what you want.  Check it out here: https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/

Comment: Certainly doable, but quite specific requirements. I doubt that a tool exists which does exactly that. You would need a bit of programming experience, e.g. for AutoIt as mentioned by @RockPaperLizard before.